# C# MySQL injection prevention for Data Creation

Tags: c#, mysql

I am running a C# function to create a database named after a user input. I'd like to prevent against SQL Injection. Normally, I would use parameters but parameters only work for data manipulation and not data creation. Code is:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    var comm = conn.CreateCommand();
    comm.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS @name";
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", id);
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Since parameters will not work for creating a database, what is the best way to go about sanitizing the input to prevent injection?

Thanks!

Comment: The issue is not with using parameters, but that sanitizing with parameters does not work for creating a database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`MySqlHelper.EscapeString("")`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlHelper_EscapeString.htm) if you won't/can't use parameters.

That's what mySQL  uses internal if you define parameters.

So you command should look like

```
comm.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + MySqlHelper.EscapeString(id);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56971713/1506667 <----this seems to contradict your answer?

Comment: @AndrewGee not even a reference on the other answer to verify  :-\