# Is it safe to not parameterize an MySQL query, and instead use the method MySqlHelper.EscapeString(string) when very large inserts are made?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql-injection, parameterized-query

For example:

```
StringBuilder sCommand = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO User (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ");
            using (MySqlConnection mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                List<string> Rows = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
                {
                    Rows.Add(string.Format("('{0}','{1}')", MySqlHelper.EscapeString("test"), MySqlHelper.EscapeString("test")));
                }
                sCommand.Append(string.Join(",", Rows));
                sCommand.Append(";");
                mConnection.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(sCommand.ToString(), mConnection))
                {
                    myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

I'd like to know if it's just as safe not to parameterize a MySQL query and, instead, to use `MySqlHelper.EscapeString` when mass inserts are made.

Comment: I'd also take into account the possible benefits of using `Prepare()` with parameterized commands versus one bulk INSERT command.

Comment: FYI there's also a new ADO.NET batching API in the pipelines, but it won't be available for a little while

Comment: It depends if you trust the input or not really. There are bypasses for the escape string (google returns the detail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the method `whatever.EscapeString(string)` instead of parameters. Simply because these two options are not equal. They are not even related. Despite the common belief, whatever escaping is not intended for protection and never has been. It has a very specific purpose and only accidentally *may* prevent an SQL injection. Whereas a parameterized query, when used properly, would *guarantee* the protection.

That said, using parameters will be *faster* for multiple inserts when you `Prepare()` the query once and then only `execute()` that prepared query in a loop.

I would also recommend to wrap your inserts in a *transaction*, it may speed the thing up significantly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will take it into account for further development. I think I'm going to try Entity Framework, although I think the database of 298 tables without foreign keys is not going to make my task any easier.